# Pandas dataframe apply list to columns auto-matching behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

Take a look at this minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = """A,B
a,1
b,1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s1))

print(df.apply(lambda x: 1 * [x.A],axis=1))
print("==================")
print(df.apply(lambda x: 2 * [x.A],axis=1))
print("==================")
print(df.apply(lambda x: 3 * [x.A],axis=1))
```

The print statements yield:

```
0    [a]
1    [b]
dtype: object
==================
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  b
==================
0    [a, a, a]
1    [b, b, b]
dtype: object
```

As you can see when the number of list elements equals the number of columns in the initial dataframe the list gets matched to those columns, in all other cases the result is just a series containing the lists as elements.

I can solve this by checking the dimensions of the dataframe and add an empty dummy column to keep the number of columns from being the same as the length of the lists if necessary, but I wish to know if there is a direct way of controlling that matching behaviour.

EDIT: The specific way I'm creating the lists in my example is only for simplicity, the lists could also be created as an output e.g. from a numpy function such as linreg or polyfit.

EDIT 2: I want my 2nd case to look like this:

```
0    [a, a]
1    [b, b]
```

EDIT 3: My real application is this to have two columns with an array or list each and then using numpy polyfit on it which yields an array whose length depends on the degree of the polynomial.

```
df["polyfit"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(np.polyfit(x[x_name],x[y_name],degree)),axis=1)
```

Comment: You can try reduce=False  parameter

Comment: Setting reduce to False does the opposite of what I want in the first case, the same in the second case, and throws an error in the third case. Setting it to True keeps everything as it is.

Comment: @Khris, do you have to use `apply(..., axis=1)`? Usually this is the slowest option...

Comment: Still I don't get what are you trying to do. What do you want to be in output exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach:

```
In [9]: df['A'].apply(list) * 1
Out[9]:
0    [a]
1    [b]
Name: A, dtype: object

In [10]: df['A'].apply(list) * 2
Out[10]:
0    [a, a]
1    [b, b]
Name: A, dtype: object

In [11]: df['A'].apply(list) * 3
Out[11]:
0    [a, a, a]
1    [b, b, b]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: That does work, but only in my specific example which I only used for simplicity. Sorry, I will edit my post to make that clear. If my lists were created in a different way, e.g. as an output of a numpy function, this wouldn't help me.